# Google sheets use arrayFormula and indirect to read cell value by having its address

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

This is how my data looks(its some kind of Gantt). B column keeps the address and C column holds the value:

[image]

I want to use arrayFormula in C column. So that upon inserting new rows, the C column is filled automatically. Is that possible?

Comment: @pgSystemTester I meant C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in C3:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F3:J8),,9^9))))
```

Comment: used your answer but only C3 and C5 have value. the rest are empty

Answer (score 1):

From the solution in this page:
https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/convert-cell-addresses-to-values-in-google-sheets/

You can use:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(TEXTJOIN("|",1,if(regexmatch(address(row(F3:F8),column(F3:I3),4),"^"&textjoin("$|^",true,B3:B8)&"$")=true,F3:I8,)),"|")))
```

Detailed explanation is on the web page.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: your answer tries to overwrite data in F column. I just want a formula on C column that uses the references provided by B column.